# two gridview but search, pagination and features (print, copy, pdf and add/remove column) is working on single one

Tags: javascript, c#

1st Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridRegistrationRequest" AllowPaging="false" runat="server" CellPadding="1" Width="100%" GridLines="None"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Record" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" CssClass="table table-striped mb-5"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#abc8e9" OnRowDataBound="GridRegistrationRequest_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Sr No' HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Officer Name & Designation">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnReqId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DocId") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnbhw" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("BhawanCode") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdwmin" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("MinistryCode") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserName" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("RegName") %>' runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Desig_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Desig_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Details(Intercom,Mobile,Email Id)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                InterCom:
            <asp:Label ID="lnl_PBXNo" Text='<%#Eval("PBXNo") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                Mobile No:
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Mobile" Text='<%# Eval("Mobile") %>' runat="server" />
                <br />
                Email ID:
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserAddress" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation" ItemStyle-CssClass="d-none" HeaderStyle-CssClass="d-none">
            <ItemTemplate>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requested Role(s)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lnl_ReqRoll" Text='<%#Eval("ReqRoll") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Division & Organization Details" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Division" Text='<%#Eval("Division") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ministry_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Ministry_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Bhawan_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Bhawan_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>,
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_State_Name" Text='<%#Eval("State_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Requested Date" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_EntryData" Text='<%#Eval("EntryData") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
                                            
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>                                               
                 <a href="../../../Public/OfficerReqestPdf.aspx?Rvisrn=<%#Eval("ReqId")%>" class="mb-2 btn-sm btn btn-outline-secondary" target="_blank">View Details</a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>


        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="On-boarding Requests" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2" ItemStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                 
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnApprove" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success form-control" OnClientClick="OpenApproved();"
                    OnCommand="lnkbtnApprove_Command" Text="Approve" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>'></asp:LinkButton><br /><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnReject" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>'
                    OnCommand="lnkbtnReject_Command" Text="Reject" OnClientClick="OpenReject();" CssClass="btn btn-warning form-control"></asp:LinkButton>
               </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                        
          
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
</asp:GridView>
```

2nd Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" CellPadding="1" Width="100%" GridLines="None" AllowPaging="false"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" EmptyDataText="No Record" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" CssClass="table table-striped mb-5"
    ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#abc8e9" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText='Sr No' HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">

            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="id" runat="server" Text="<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Officer Name & Designation">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnReqId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnId" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("DocId") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnbhw" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("BhawanCode") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdwmin" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("MinistryCode") %>' />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserName" Text='<%# Eval("UserName") %>' runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text='<%# Eval("RegName") %>' runat="server" /><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Desig_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Desig_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contact Details(Intercom,Mobile,Email Id)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%--InterCom:
            <asp:Label ID="lnl_PBXNo" Text='<%#Eval("PBXNo") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label><br />--%>
                Mobile No:
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Mobile" Text='<%# Eval("Mobile") %>' runat="server" />
                <br />
                Email ID:
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_UserAddress" Text='<%#Eval("Email") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation" ItemStyle-CssClass="d-none" HeaderStyle-CssClass="d-none">
            <ItemTemplate>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Role(s)" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lnl_ReqRoll" Text='<%#Eval("ReqRoll") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Organization Details" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <%-- <asp:Label ID="lbl_Division" Text='<%#Eval("Division") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label><br />--%>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Ministry_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Ministry_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label><br />
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_Bhawan_Name" Text='<%#Eval("Bhawan_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>,
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_State_Name" Text='<%#Eval("State_Name") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
       <%-- <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date From" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>                                                                                            
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>--%>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Appointment Link" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>
               <%-- <asp:HiddenField ID="hdLink" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("User_Loc_ID") %>' />
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hdFullLink" runat="server" />
                <asp:Label ID="lblLink" runat="server" > </asp:Label>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtnAppointment" runat="server" CssClass="mb-2 btn btn-outline-dark" Text="CopyLink" OnCommand="lnkbtnAppointment_Command"></asp:LinkButton>
                 --%>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>                                       
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Action" HeaderStyle-CssClass="p-2">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:LinkButton CssClass="btn btn-primary form-control" ID="lnkUpdate" runat="server" OnClientClick="OpenUpdate();" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>' Text="Update" OnCommand="lnkUpdate_Command"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lbkbtnInactive" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-success form-control mt-2" OnCommand="lbkbtnInactive_Command" Visible="false"
                    Text="Inactive" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ReqId") %>' OnClientClick="OpenInactive();"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>

    </Columns>
    <%--<PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" Position="Bottom" FirstPageText="Previous" LastPageText="Next" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pagination-ys"/>--%>
</asp:GridView>
```

Javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function () {
          
          useDatatable();
      });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function useDatatable() {
        $('#<%=Gridview.ClientID%>').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("#<%= Gridview.ClientID%>").find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
            retrieve: true,

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'copyHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                    title: "Officer List",
                    orientation: 'Landscape',
                    pageSize: 'A4',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    },
                    customize: function (doc) {
                        processDoc(doc);
                    }
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    exportOptions: {
                        columns: ':visible'
                    }
                },
                'colvis',
            ]
        });
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        bindRequestedGrid();
    });

    $("document").ready(function () {
        bindRequestedGrid();

    });

    function bindRequestedGrid() {
        $('#<%=Gridview.ClientID%>').prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($("#<%=Gridview.ClientID%>").find("tr:first"))).DataTable({
             retrieve: true,
            });
    }                   
</script>
```

it is to show the buttons for print, pdf, copy, Add/Remove column and search and pagination

This is the script i use for both the gridview. I am not able to understand what is wrong while applying it on both

i have to hide gridview on page load and show it when i click on button
Gridview binds perfectly but searchable features are not working
it imposes that i should bind gridview on page load itself to make it work

Comment: It would be useful to see more code, in particular, your GridViews

Comment: i place the script in update panel. to resolve the issue i just place the script outside update panel. thank and regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the script outside of the update panel.